# Are camping washing machines actually effective?

Tags: cleaning

I was checking these small hand powered or electric powered washing machines, such as [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/oneConcept-Camping-Washing-Machine-operation/dp/B00B0100BC/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1418030849&sr=8-3&keywords=camping+washing+machine), and I was wondering if they are actually effective. Do they wash properly? Are they worth the price?

Comment: can you give an example/link to what you are talking about.

Comment: @nivag [This one for example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/oneConcept-Camping-Washing-Machine-operation/dp/B00B0100BC/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1418030849&sr=8-3&keywords=camping+washing+machine)

Comment: I think you would be better off reading product reviews than asking this question here.